# No any sign from typescript when use with "mongoose" and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to use typescript with mongoose and NodeJs
I tried to make arbitrarily error but the IDE doesn't show indication for error message.

UserSchema file:

```
import { Schema, Document, model } from "mongoose";

export interface IProduct extends Document {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  dodo: string;
}

const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true }
});

export default model<IProduct>("Product", productSchema, "products");
```

The route file:

```
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import Product, { IProduct } from "../models/product";

const router = Router();

router.post("/", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

  const product: IProduct = new Product({
    name: "ahmed",
    price: "this should throw an error"
  });

  product.save()
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Ahmed Hossam this is not a problem related to the programming, it is problem related to the IDE you are using, please use this platform for solving your programming doubts. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for welcoming. I think this's a problem related to programming because typescript works well in react projects on the same IDE